# BroadcstReciver и AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

У меня такая задача, нужно через определенные отрезки времени обмениваться с сайтом информацией и в силу свое малого познания android я делаю так:

```
public class TimeToServer extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TimeToServer", "Запуск синхронизации");
        Sinchron_bd.performClick();
    }
}
```

Ну думаю понятно, я просто инициализирую клик, который запускает обмен с сайтом. Проблема в том, что в android 5.1 и 7.0 это срабатывает, но в android 7.1.2 нет, как лучше сделать данную функцию?

Для ясности вот так устанавливаю время для связи с сервером:

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent time_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeToServer.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, time_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // На случай, если мы ранее запускали активити, а потом поменяли время, откажемся от уведомления
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    // Устанавливаем разовое напоминание
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time_to_server, pendingIntent);
```

И вот что делает кнопка:

```
View.OnClickListener f_sinchron = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startOnSinhronization_by_time(true);
        if (isOnline()) {
            // TODO: Получение курсов валют
            ValutaRub();
            ValutaEur();

            new Syncron().execute();
        } else {
            showMessage(R.string.not_internet);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Попробуйте Timer или new Handler().postDelayed()

Comment: @РусланЯгупов  Они мне не подходят, к тому же они не срабатывают когда приложение свернуто, а мне надо чтоб срабатывали.

Comment: Как понимаю просто вызываете Api из прилаги?

Comment: @РусланЯгупов я не особо разбираюсь, но я просто запускаю 2 метода через "левую" асинхронную библиотеку, и один метод AsyncTask и на android 7.1.2 вообще клик не отрабатывает хотя в лог запись выводится.

Comment: Вообще рекомендую вынести логику получения курсов в сервис и отправлять их в активити или виджет, но может быть проблема с Doze

Comment: @РусланЯгупов но проблема то не в получении курсов валют, а в ... даже не знаю как выразится, ну думаю в кнопке

Comment: Так именно, у вас активити вообще может быть уничтожена, а сервис убить сложнее

Comment: @РусланЯгупов т.е. если я всю эту "жесть" запихну в сервис и буду их оттуда вызывать, у меня все станет работать??

Comment: Для ясности дополню, кнопки и прочее ничего туда не нужно совать. Создаешь сервис там делаешь таймер, по которому будет вызываться API, как ответ придет посылаешь интент с курсами и ловишь его а активити, ну это  уж если совсем нужно чтобы постоянно данные актуальные были, а не для открытой активити

Comment: @РусланЯгупов что-то я так тихо подозреваю сервис мне не подойдёт, просто дело в том что время через которое происходит синхронизация пользователь может менять, там на выбор есть несколько вариантов - это 1, если пользователь сам нажмет кнопку синхронизации то я должен показать, что идет синхронизация, а на сколько я помню сервис не может взаимодействовать с граф. интерфейсом, поэтому думаю сервис тут не прокатит.

Comment: Почему не может взаимодействовать, кидаете Intent-ы друг другу и все